# How to compute numbers rich in divisors

Tags: number-theory

I vaguely remember there is a notion of numbers rich in divisors, i.e. (number of divisors of N)/N is comparatively large. What's their name? Given a number M, how could I find such a number in its neighbourhood?

Comment: [Primorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $p_n \#$ have quite some divisors.

Answer (score 4):

This might be interesting:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Moreover if you care about sums:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number

Comment: wow I never knew pure mathematicians even studied these things. The names themselves are funny enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking about [smooth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).

How to find such things?  I suppose you could just multiply small numbers together until you are within the "neighbourhood".  If you overshoot, take out some factors and replace them with other factors.